# Same Component but Different Url Path in Vue

Tags: vue.js, url, path, routes, vue-router

I would like to have different url(Consumer and Seller) for the same component SingleProduct, which the following codes works well:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/:name",
    name: "SingleProductSeller",
    component: SingleProduct
  },
  {
    path: "/seller/:name",
    name: "SingleProductConsumer",
    component: SingleProduct,
  },
]
```

Instead of separating into two, is there any other method?
For example, is it possible to make an alias with params like following and how to?

```
  {
    path: "/:name",
    name: "SingleProduct",
    component: SingleProduct,
    alias: "/seller/:name/",
    props: true,
  },
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"is it possible to make an alias"_  yes ~ https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is **alias with params (:name)** allowed as well? As I read from somewhere else that it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alias` feature of the **vue-router**. It is nicely explained in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect).

However, you should avoid this if possible since you are using **dynamic path fragments** and these are two different routes conceptually and so should be distinct routes even if they point to the same component. You will run into bookmarking problem - **The page won't transition to the same route even since they are just aliases**.

If you really want to avoid DRY, you should use simple function-based abstraction instead of relying on aliases:

```
function makeSingleProductRoute(name, path) {
    return {
        name, path,
        component: SingleProduct
        // Reusable guards if required.
    };
}


const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        makeSingleProductRoute("SingleProductConsumer", "/seller/:name"),
        makeSingleProductRoute("SingleProductSeller", "/:name")
    ]
});
```

Comment: IMO, I'd do the `/seller` route first as it has a more specific pattern to match. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority

Comment: @Phil, Indeed, you are right. Seller should come first.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have read the documents before and wondered if **alias with params** is allowed. As I read from somewhere else that alias with params is not supported for **vue-router** , and can't find additional information from the Vue website.

Comment: @Qness, Yes, that is right. Dynamic paths do not work with aliases.